# Python Exception

Tags: python, exception

How do I know the all possible exceptions thrown by a python statement ?
I am trying to implement exception handling in python but I don't know that how many types of exceptions can be thrown by a python statement.

Comment: Have you checked [Built-in Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html)?

Comment: In general you don't, you have to look it up in the docs or even the source.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look it up in documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/

However, if you want to catch any exception just don't explicitly declare one:

```
def foo(value):
    try:
       x = 1 / value
    except ZeroDivisionError:
       print "Can't divide by zero"
    except:
        print "TypeError ends here"

>>> foo(0)
Can't divide by zero
>>> foo('error')
TypeError ends here
```

The TypeError that results from trying to divide 1 by a string is caught by the undeclared `except:`

Comment: Or, even better, `except Exception as e:` which will catch all exceptions and at least let you print the error messages.